# Trying to reconcile the amount sent versus amount transacted

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

[image: Transaction fees]

Newbie here trying to understand how an amount sent from coinbase gets put onto the block at a different value.

In this transaction, I sent 0.55076816 LTC to a wallet.

- There’s a network fee of 0.00100816 which means I receive 0.54976.

But what I don’t understand is the figure 0.57441138 on the right hand [BlockCypher screen](https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/tx/70dc018e99d5223ce01901f4fcef81e4f1930bcd1c0126d9d5631d724d0d86f6/).

Where did the extra 0.02364322 LTC (0.57441138-0.55076816) come from that I didn't send from Coinbase???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I owe you $8, but all I have is a $10 bill. I'll make a transaction that spends my $10 bill and delivers $8 to you and returns $2 to me. The extra 0.02364322 LTC is Coinbase's change, just as the extra $2 is my change.

Coinbase didn't happen to have precisely 0.55177632 LTC in an unspent transaction output, they had 0.5734121 LTC. So they returned some change to themselves.